# How to solve Exit code 3 with IntelliJ IDEA for R code

Tags: r, intellij-idea

I recently started using IntelliJ as an R IDE and it was working fine at the beginning

However, when i Try running a code line with list.files() it produces the lines below without any additional info.

*Process was terminated

*Process finished with exit code 3

when i try running my program in Rstudio, it works fine, but when i bring it back to IntelliJ it does not work.

i was trying to load multiple shape files or image files by filters

what could be the problem?

Comment: I am having the same problem, but only if I assign the file names to a variable. Just listing them works. It also works if there is only one file.

Did you try asking JetBrains support directly (not the community)?

Comment: The problem seems to relate more generally to large character vectors, which is what list.files would return if you have enough files in the directory. I have raised the issue with JetBrains - let's see what they say.

Comment: @user1683586 I did try ask them, i have not received any answers yet, which is weird cause those guys are quick to respond to issues. Please do share with me if they respond to you first

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the September 2020 version of the R-plugin.
JetBrains are aware of it and so there will hopefully be a fix soon.

In the meantime, the August 2020 version works for me.
So I uninstalled the plugin, downloaded a different version and installed the plugin from disk.

Here are the R-plugin downloads:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij/versions

Comment: Thank you for your response, i did what you suggested and it worked, so i will stick to that untill the new update is released.